# Prompting dialog from a icon whe clicked in android

Tags: android, notifications, dialog, custom-notification

I have a notification icon and I want to open a custom dialog when icon is clicked see image for example i have created the layout and called the alert dialog but it is showing in middle of the screen.[image: example how I want it to be] 
   [image: Java code for alert Dialog]
[image: notification_screen]

Comment: Alert dialogs are supposed to appear at center

Answer (score 2):

```
You can define gravity for an alert dialog by using following piece of code.

WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = resolutionDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    wmlp.x = 0; // specify x axis position
    wmlp.y = 0; // specify y axis position
    yourDialog.show();
```

Comment: I used the PopWindow  and it is exactly working how I wanted.But thank you anyway for helping.